Performance issue when using an inequality in the WHERE clause
I have the following code on a SQL Server Azure Managed Instance and the performance is pretty terrible.
INSERT INTO #CU WITH (TABLOCKX) (LA_ID, CU_ID)
SELECT la.LA_ID,
       c2.CU_ID
FROM #la la
    INNER JOIN dbo.T1 c ON c.CU_ID = la.CU_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.T1 c2 ON c2.Parent_CU_ID = c.Parent_CU_ID
WHERE c.Parent_CU_ID > 0
      AND c.CU_ID <> c2.CU_ID
      AND la.Flag1 = 1
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #cid WHERE c2.CU_ID = ID)

I have a filtered index on T1.Flag, and if I remove the inequality the performance is more than acceptable (5 minutes down to 10 seconds) so I'm confident my issue is with the inequality but I can't think of any patterns that will give me the same results, but perform better. Any suggestions? Plan


If someone asked you this without a query plan what would you tell them, Kenneth?

I'd probably send them to @ErikReasonableRatesDarling since he knows everything. Honestly, since I obviously simplified things down I'll have to see if I can generate one. that looks right. Mostly I was looking for general patterns to try.

The trouble is that this pattern isn’t a generally bad one. The devil will be in the details, as a wiser man who also has Reasonable Rates™️ once said.

@ErikReasonableRatesDarling Plan added along with a better version the actual query.

#TeamLegacyCE
Since the issue is not with table-level cardinality, you may want to force using the legacy cardinality estimator. Being in Compatibility Level 150 uses different join estimation which looks to be quite wildly incorrect.

You can do that with this hint:
INSERT INTO 
    #CU 
WITH 
    (TABLOCKX) 
(
    LA_ID, 
    CU_ID
)
SELECT 
    la.LA_ID,
    c2.CU_ID
FROM #la la
INNER JOIN dbo.T1 AS c 
  ON c.CU_ID = la.CU_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.T1 AS c2 
  ON c2.Parent_CU_ID = c.Parent_CU_ID
WHERE c.Parent_CU_ID > 0
AND   c.CU_ID <> c2.CU_ID
AND   la.Flag1 = 1
AND   EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 
        1/0 
    FROM #cid AS ci
    WHERE c2.CU_ID = ci.ID
)
OPTION(USE HINT('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'));

There are of course other issues, which may be corrected with better join estimation.

Low plan cost: The 16k row estimate results in an estimated cost of ~3.4 Query Bucks, which gets you a serial plan. That is a bad path to choose when your actuals are 144,688,210 rows and 61,962,838 rows.

No Batch Mode: Batch Mode On Row Store would be a much more palatable choice along with a parallel plan when joining that many rows. Again, it may kick in naturally with a properly estimated and costed plan, but if it doesn't you will need to play the usual tricks for the optimizer to choose it.


all that aside
I would probably want to double check that this query is written correctly. Starting with row counts in the mid-ten thousands and producing joined results of 144 million and 62 million rows seems quite tawdry.
Further, even correcting the above items will only stand to reduce query execution time to around 4 minutes (though perhaps lower if the insert ends up in a parallel zone as intended by the TABLOCK hint).
That likely can't be fixed, since you're on a damnable Microsoft cloud product with disks made of hot asphalt. Inserting 62 million rows there will continue to be a sticking point, which is why I asked if the query is written correctly.
If it is written correctly, you may find some relief by adding a DISTINCT or ROW_NUMBER into the mix. Many of those rows being inserted are likely unnecessary duplicates which could be removed from the final result.

Adding the FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION hint and moving the create clustered index until after the insert got me down to a reasonable level (~1.5 minutes, 1 min for the insert and 30 seconds for the index creation). Unfortunately, the 61 mil results ARE distinct (the new estimate is 112 mil FYI). I will have someone look at this query for correctness though. Thanks for the help!
